# Implementing Authorization Code Grant Flow with Microsoft Graph API in Angular and Node.js

Tags: angular, express, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, token

I am working on integrating Microsoft Graph API into my Angular application, and I need to implement the Authorization Code Grant Flow for secure authentication. I have my own application login page, and I want to retrieve an authorization code, exchange it for an access token from my backend (Node.js + Express API), and then store the token in the database for future use.

Here's an overview of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. **User Authentication**

- Users log in through my custom Angular application login page
- I want to initiate the Microsoft Graph API consent flow to obtain permissions for reading Outlook calendars

2. **Authorization Code Retrieval**

- After the user grants consent, I need to obtain an authorization code.

3. **Token Exchange**

- I will send this authorization code to my Node.js + Express backend
- The backend should exchange the authorization code for an access token using the Microsoft Graph API

4. **Token Storage**

- Once the access token is obtained, I want to securely store it in my database for future use

5. **API Requests**

- When the user interacts with the calendar feature, I will retrieve the access token from the database and use it to make requests to the Microsoft Graph API

Thanks! any help will apricated

Comment: Did you already look at the MSAL library on github? It contains most of your topics. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular

Comment: @CharlieV Yes I cheeked there but didn't able to find anything according my above use case

Comment: The MSAL wrapper will allow you to do steps 1, 2 and 5 without having to store the token. Why would you want to store the token? It will expire after a while and you'll need to request a new one.

Comment: @CharlieV Because, after a user connects their Outlook calendar to my application, there's an ongoing need for communication between the user's calendar and my application via the API. Storing the token allows for seamless and uninterrupted interaction with the API on the server side when the user accesses the calendar page